# How to connect to on-premise sql server through self-hosted Integrated runtime(linked service) in Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect to an on-prem SQL server from azure but I am getting confusion on username and password while connecting.
What username and password should i be using while creating a linked service? I tried using sql and windows authentication but it does not work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory needs connectivity to your on premises network. In order to accomplish this the last I checked need to have a [Data Factory Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime) configured on the network.  This would allow for secure communication.

Here are the steps on how to move data between [on prem SQL to Azure SQL via Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-sql-azure-adf)

As for linked service the last time I checked only supported SQL auth.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the intend is to connect to the In premise SQL from ADF . You will have to install something called Self Hosted runtime , How to install , please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) . Once you have installed the SHIR , while creating the linked service you will have to selected the SHIR from the drop down  and it should work fine .